# Why can't I get Google's Python test to work?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to use Google's Python intro (https://developers.google.com/edu/python/exercises/basic) to get myself started on programming.

Based on these instructions it gave me, I wrote the code below:

```
# Given an int count of a number of donuts, return a string
# of the form 'Number of donuts: <count>', where <count> is the number
# passed in. However, if the count is 10 or more, then use the word 'many'
# instead of the actual count.
# So donuts(5) returns 'Number of donuts: 5'
# and donuts(23) returns 'Number of donuts: many'
def donuts(count):
  if count < 10:
    numberofdonuts = count
  else:
    numberofdonuts = 'many'
  print 'Number of donuts:', str(numberofdonuts)
  return
```

If I just tell Python to print the code I've written, it comes out looking exactly like the instructions say it should (e.g.: "Number of donuts: 4"). But when it goes through the test module that Google provides:

```
# Provided simple test() function used in main() to print
# what each function returns vs. what it's supposed to return.
def test(got, expected):
  if got == expected:
    prefix = ' OK '
  else:
    prefix = '  X '
  print '%s got: %s expected: %s' % (prefix, repr(got), repr(expected))


# Provided main() calls the above functions with interesting inputs,
# using test() to check if each result is correct or not.
def main():
  print 'donuts'
  # Each line calls donuts, compares its result to the expected for that call.
  test(donuts(4), 'Number of donuts: 4')
  test(donuts(9), 'Number of donuts: 9')
  test(donuts(10), 'Number of donuts: many')
  test(donuts(99), 'Number of donuts: many')
```

It keeps returning an "X" and saying it got "None," like this:

```
donuts
Number of donuts: 4
  X  got: None expected: 'Number of donuts: 4'
Number of donuts: 9
  X  got: None expected: 'Number of donuts: 9'
Number of donuts: many
  X  got: None expected: 'Number of donuts: many'
Number of donuts: many
  X  got: None expected: 'Number of donuts: many'
```

I'm assuming Google knows how to write Python just fine, but I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out how the test module works and comparing my results to what it seems to want, and I can't get anywhere?

I figure I'm missing something incredibly basic here....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function *prints*, and does not *return* the value.

`print` writes to your console or terminal. The caller doesn't receive the result.

Instead of using `print`, return the string:

```
def donuts(count):
  if count < 10:
    numberofdonuts = count
  else:
    numberofdonuts = 'many'
  return 'Number of donuts: ' + str(numberofdonuts)
```